# Is it possible for a woman to be Imam al-jama’a for women?

Tags: salat, women, shia-sunni, imam-al-jamaah

I know that majority of Shia Marja’al-Taqlid considered it as a permissible issue for women to stand as the Imam-al-Jama’ah for women. (Not for men)/[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/ha167)

But I’d like to know if it is possible for a woman to be Imam al-Jama’a? ( for wajib prayer(Salat))

*Note: I am looking for the viewpoint of Sunni brothers.*

Answer (score 2):

The majority allow it. There of the four schools, Shafi, Hanafi and Hanabils allow a woman to lead a woman only congregations. The Hanafi consider it Makrooh. The Malikis say it is not allowed.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_as_imams#Women-only_congregations

This link to an Arabic Fatwa by the General Authority of Islamic Affairs & Endowments in the UAE with the same answer:

[www.awqaf.ae](http://www.awqaf.ae/Fatwa.aspx?SectionID=9&RefID=3966)